# Using string variables to be part of tsql code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On tsql, I want to use variable as part of tsql code according to some conditions, is there a way to do the following:

```
DECLARE @mode BINARY = 0
DECLARE @stringCode VARCHAR(100)
.
.
.
if(@mode = 1)(
    @stringCode VARCHAR(100) = 'charindex(",", rtrim(col1_name), col2_name)'
)ELSE(
    @stringCode VARCHAR(100) = '1=1'
)

SELECT col1_name, col2_name, col3_name
    FROM table1_name AS T1
    INNER JOIN table2_name AS T2
    ON @stringCode
```

The last query using the variable `@stringCode` as part of the code.

Well, it did not work like that, so I wanted to know if I could possibly apply this?

***Please note that this code is just a test to demonstrate what I want to do***

Comment: If you want to do this, then you need to learn about dynamic SQL.  If you are attempting this and don't know what dynamic SQL is, you may need to learn about SQL in general.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will read about dynamic SQL. I am glad that it is possible though

Answer (score 1):

All you need is 'sp_executesql' system stored proc. It takes a string containing the query as input:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT col1_name, col2_name, col3_name
    FROM table1_name AS T1
    INNER JOIN table2_name AS T2
    ON ' + @stringCode

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this, but not sure if those are right join conditions.

```
if(@mode = 1)(
    SELECT col1_name, col2_name, col3_name
    FROM table1_name AS T1
    INNER JOIN table2_name AS T2
       ON charindex(",", rtrim(col1_name), col2_name)
)ELSE(
    SELECT col1_name, col2_name, col3_name
    FROM table1_name AS T1
    INNER JOIN table2_name AS T2
       ON 1=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, this what I am using now, but the reason I need to use a variable because there are more conditions and I also want to apply the same concepts in different ways. Your suggestion is good but not using what I am looking for

Comment: Then you need go for the dynamic SQL. as suggested in comments ;) , But again, you should double check those `JOIN`  conditions, looks very weird

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote the conditions just to demonstrate the code and they do look weird :)

Comment: Thanks @Juan Carlos Oropeza